# ASP.net MVC 4.5.1 and bootstrap datepicker 1.5.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am trying to put validation on some dates that I have on a form in asp.net mvc 4.5.1. I've tried so many things! I've tried just regular data annotation validation, and I've tried different datepicker versions. The issue I have is that I need for the program to force the user to enter 4-digit year. In the example here: http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-datepicker/ it works perfectly...exactly like I need it to work. I've copied the code as best I can and modified it to my environment (I have several dates, so I want to validate by the datepicker2 class.

Here are my includes:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.0-dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.0-dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.0-dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my start of my form and view (just the first date field that I need to validate):

```
<body style="background-color: #636363">
    <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 16px;">
        <div style="width:60%;float: left; padding: 15px;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MainForm" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

               <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_Project_Start, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 CreateEditFieldNamesSpan" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DT_Project_Start, new { @class = "form-control datepicker2" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_Project_Start)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the model:

```
[DisplayName("Start Date")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date not valid.")]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime? DT_Project_Start { get; set; }
```

Here is the script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.datepicker2')
         .datepicker({
             format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
         })
         .on('changeDate', function(e) {
             // Revalidate the date field
             $('.datepicker2').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
         });

     $('.datepicker2').formValidation({
         framework: 'bootstrap',
         icon: {
             valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
             invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
             validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
         },
         fields: {
             date: {
                 validators: {
                     date: {
                         format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                         message: 'The date is not a valid'
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 });
    </script>
```

The datepicker displays and works, but the date validation does not (ie: not allowing invalid date on the field itself). Any ideas what I have wrong? I am new to mvc, just trying to figure all of this out and have tried so many things to make this work.

Comment: Did you try to use `Html.EditorFor` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor` ?

Comment: try with an `id` instead of `class`

Comment: Using EditorFor causes problems with Chrome...conflicts with the HTML datepicker or something. Requires that we use yyyy/mm/dd format, which user does not want to do. I think my code is actually wrong somewhere....do I need to specify the actual field name everywhere that I have "date"?
Do you mean id=datepicker2?